# Is the union of two conservative extensions of a theory conservative?

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory

##### Background/Motivation

A *theory* T over a signature(language) Σ is a set of formulae over Σ. These formulae are called the *non-logical axioms* of T.
To talk about what is provable in T we can agree on Hilbert calculus and first-order logic.

A theory $ T' $ over $ Σ' $ is said to be an *extension* of a theory $ T $ over $ Σ $ if

- every sort/relation symbol/function symbol in $ Σ $ is also a sort/relation symbol/function symbol in $ Σ' $
- Every non-logical axiom of $ T $ is a non-logical axiom of $ T' $.

An extension $ T' $ of $ T $ is said to be *conservative* (over $ T $) if every formula over $ T $ that is provable in $ T' $ is also provable in $ T $

$ T' := T_1 \cup T_2 $ is a theory with signature $Σ_1 \cup Σ_2 $ and $Σ_1 \cap Σ_2 = Σ$ and is exactly the disjoint union of the nonlogical axioms of $T_1$ and $T_2$. (By this I mean that the instances of the axioms are united, and axiom schemas are not automatically applied to each other's signatures but rather kept separate and treated as an infinite set of axioms. Every non-logical axiom in $T'$ is a nonlogical axiom in $T_1$ or $T_2$)

---

##### Question

If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are extensions of a theory $T$, then so is $T_1 \cup T_2$ . If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are conservative, and therefore add no new theorems to $ T $ , is the same true for $T'$ ?

> Is $ T' := T_1 \cup T_2 $ a conservative extension of $ T $, if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are conservative extensions of $T$ ?

And if not, what would a simple counterexample be?

---

##### Attempts

So far I have

- considered the weaker question (due to conservative over T ⇒ consistent over T):

> Is $ T' $ a consistent extension of $ T $, if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are conservative extensions of $T$ ?

- tried to find or construct counterexamples specifically for this purpose but failed
- tried to prove the statement by induction over a hilbert-style proof tree. The main problem were the logical axioms at the leaves, which being axiom schemes, allow for a "mixing" of the signatures, making it difficult to "split" the prooftree into separate branches for $T_1$ and $T_2$. I still find this attempt promising but haven't made much progress yet. I also took into account the conservativity of a language extension.
- found no sources on this, especially since taking the union of theories as I have seems uncommon, and because it seems most material on (conservative) extensions takes a model theoretic rather than proof-theoretic approach.

Comment: Certainly not. There is any number of trivial counterexamples; the simplest I can think of is let $T$ be the empty theory in the empty language, $T_1$ the theory $\exists x\,R(x)$ in language $\{R(x)\}$, and $T_2$ the theory $\neg\exists x\,R(x)$ in the same language. If you want some positive results, you should look at variants of Robinson’s joint consistency theorem.

Comment: I was implicitely reading the question with $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ disjoint extention of $\Sigma$ ( as in $\Sigma = \Sigma_1 \cap \Sigma_2$ ), which rules out the most obvious counter-example, is it what was intended ?

Comment: The question does not state anything like that. But if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are conservative extensions of $T$ in languages $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ (resp.) such that $\Sigma_1\cap\Sigma_2=\Sigma$, then $T_1\cup T_2$ is indeed a conservative extension of $T$. This is a variant of Robinson’s joint consistency theorem, as I mentioned.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I agree it is not clearly said, but the paragraph explaining what $T'$ gave me the impression that it was the intent (at least that's how I read the question before you commented - but that might be my category theory oriented mind that always assume all sets that are not clearly introduced as subset of something are disjoints) - in any case your second comment is a much more interesting answer to the question which I think you should post as an answer.

Comment: @SimonHenry All right, done.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek thank you, yes, I did mean that Σ_1∩Σ_2=Σ and forgot to explicitly mention it. I will edit the question to fix this, and I apologize if editing such an important detail in hindsight is considered bad form

Comment: @SimonHenry You might be interested in the categorical version of Robinson's theorem treated in Makkai's "On Gabbay's proof of the Craig interpolation theorem for intuitionistic predicate logic". There he proves that if in a pushout of Boolean categories one leg is conservative, so is the parallel leg. Interestingly, this fails for coherent categories, unless the legs are Heyting functors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is true (and somewhat nontrivial). That is, if $T$ is a theory in a language $\Sigma$, and $T_1$ and $T_2$ are conservative extensions of $T$ in languages $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ (respectively) such that $\Sigma_1\cap\Sigma_2=\Sigma$, then $T_1\cup T_2$ is a conservative extension of $T$. This is a form of [Robinson’s joint consistency theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%27s_joint_consistency_theorem).

To derive it from a more common formulation of the joint consistency theorem that requires $T$ to be complete, let $\phi$ be any $\Sigma$-sentence such that $T\nvdash\phi$; we will show $T_1\cup T_2\nvdash\phi$. Since $T\nvdash\phi$, there exists a complete consistent $\Sigma$-theory $T'\supseteq T\cup\{\neg\phi\}$. Since $T_1$ and $T_2$ are conservative over $T$, the theories $T_1\cup T'$ and $T_2\cup T'$ are consistent. But then $T_1\cup T_2\cup T'$ is also consistent by the joint consistency theorem, hence $T_1\cup T_2\nvdash\phi$.

The requirement $\Sigma_1\cap\Sigma_2=\Sigma$ is essential, otherwise there are very simple counterexamples: e.g., let $T$ be the empty theory in the empty language, $T_1$ the theory $\{\exists x\,R(x)\}$ in language $\{R(x)\}$, and $T_2=\{\neg\exists x\,R(x)\}$ in the same language.

Comment: Usually the "common formulation" of  the joint consistency theorem is proven using the Conservative Extension formulation, I will soon write an answer that proves the variation without assuming the Robinson’s joint consistency theorem

Comment: @Holo I don’t think I’ve ever seen it proved in that way. The most common proof of the joint consistency theorem is to derive it from the joint consistency lemma (if $A$ and $B$ are structures such that $A\restriction\Sigma\equiv B\restriction\Sigma$, then there are elementary extensions $A'\succeq A$ and $B'\succeq B$ such that $A'\restriction\Sigma\simeq B'\restriction\Sigma$). This naturally proves the version with $T$ complete. Another proof is to derive it from Craig’s interpolation theorem, which in turn can be proved (in a sequent form) by induction on the length of a cut-free proof ...

Comment: ... using the cut elimination theorem. (More common proofs of Craig’s interpolation theorem derive it from the joint consistency theorem.) In this way you prove whatever version of the joint consistency theorem you want with essentially the same effort.

Comment: Interesting, the proof I know for the joint consistency theorem is to show the conservative variation using Craig’s interpolation (see my answer) and from there the standard variation is immediate, I guess that the difference comes to preference of using models or being purely syntactic

Comment: If I understand correctly, the joint consistency theorem is being applied three times to show that $T_1 \cup T'$ , $T_2 \cup T'$ and then finally $T_1 \cup T_2 \cup T'$ are consistent. But how do we know $T_1 \cap T'$ / $(T_1 \cup T_2) \cap T'$ are complete? Perhaps this is a simple fact on intersections with general complete theories I do not know?

Comment: @GiacomoCozzi No, the joint consistency theorem is applied only once. $T_1\cup T'$ and $T_2\cup T'$ are consistent because of the conservativity of $T_1$ and $T_2$ over $T$.

Answer (score 7):

As Emil pointed out, assuming $\Sigma=\Sigma_1\cap\Sigma_2$, the union of 2 such theories is always conservative extension, Emil had proven it using the standard formulation Robinson’s joint consistency theorem, some places first prove the conservative extension variation and then uses it to get to the standard formulation, so here is a proof of this variation without assuming the Robinson’s joint consistency theorem but instead assumes Craig's interpolation (note that Craig's interpolation is as hard to prove as proving the joint consistency theorem in a different way, so it is not really "easier"):

Let $\phi$ be a sentence in $\Sigma$ provable in $T'$ and not provable in $T$.

Because $T_1$ is conservative, $\phi$ is also not provable there, but because $T_2 \cup (T_1\cup \{\lnot\phi\})$ is inconsistent there must be some $\psi$ provable in $T_2$ such that $\lnot\psi$ is provable in $T_1\cup\{\lnot\phi\}$ (this is a surprisingly tricky lemma when $T_1,T_2$ are not with the same language, it follows from Craig's interpolation), in particular $\psi$ and $\lnot\psi$ are sentences in $\Sigma$. Furthermore we have that $\lnot\phi\implies\lnot\psi$ is provable in $T_1$ and in the language $\Sigma$.

But because $T_2$ is conservative it means that $\psi$ is provable in $T$, and because $T_1$ is conservative we have $\lnot\phi\implies\lnot\psi$ also provable in $T$, but from $\psi$ and $\lnot\phi\implies\lnot\psi$ follows $\phi$ in $T$.

Note that the standard variation of the joint consistency theorem follows immediately, as any (consistent) extension of a complete theory is conservative.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I fixed up the wording to be more clear

Comment: If you use interpolation, you can prove conservativity directly rather than by contradiction. That is, if $T'\vdash\phi$ for a $\Sigma$-sentence $\phi$, there are (just by collecting the axioms used) $\psi_1$ in $\Sigma_1$ and $\psi_2$ in $\Sigma_2$ such that $T_1\vdash\psi_1$, $T_2\vdash\psi_2$, and $\vdash\psi_1\to(\psi_2\to\phi)$. By Craig’s interpolation, there is a $\Sigma$-sentence $\psi$ such that $\vdash\psi_1\to\psi$ and $\vdash\psi\to(\psi_2\to\phi)$. Then $T_1\vdash\psi$, thus $T\vdash\psi$ by conservativity, and likewise $T_2\vdash\psi\to\phi$ implies $T\vdash\psi\to\phi$, thus ...

Comment: ... $T\vdash\phi$. So, for example, this applies also to theories over intuitionistic logic (where the argument with negations does not work).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek good catch, I'll admit I'm usually loose with my use of LEM, so I tend to not notice "useless contradictions"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Let $\phi$ be a non-theorem in the language of $T$, and let $c,d$ be two fresh symbols for constants. Now we can take $T_1$ to add the axiom $(c = d) \Rightarrow \phi$, and $T_2$ to add the axiom $c = d$.

Comment: Are there conterexamples for $\Sigma_1 \cap \Sigma_2 = \Sigma$?